# Anyone know of a javascript removal tool for html

Tags: javascript, html

I am having issues with an Ebay template, if I try to upload it get's kicked back to me saying that it cannot contain javascript, I'm assuming that it's in the picture rollover option (mouseover pic enlarging tool) Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm not real Java intuitive.

Comment: Can you show us the source code ?

Answer (score 2):

Just delete anything between the `<script>` and `</script>` tags. Or perhaps post the code snippet here so we can tell you what to remove.

Comment: I think you mean &lt;script&gt; and &lt;/script&gt; tags (if that doesn't get mangled in the comment)

Answer (score 1):

The template should have a HTML file inside.

1. Search for ... parts and remove them as mentioned before.
2. Search for instances of onmouseover="...", onmouseout="..." and generally anything that looks like , removing the onsomeevent="dosomething" part.